# iis7.5 mvc2 404 and 500.24 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7.5, http-status-code-404

This is my first time deploying an MVC2 app (.NET4) on IIS7.5. I'm using StructureMap and Fluent NHibernate, and everything runs fine locally using integrated security.  The application does render the first page (`controllername/pagename`), but throws an error on the next one which is (`controllername/pagename/id`).

I have ran `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir`.
HttpRedirection and HttpExceptions are enabled.

**This is the 404 error from View Source:**

> [HttpException]: The controller for path '/conrollername/pagename/1' was not found or does not implement IController.
>      at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
>      at CustomerResponses.Infrastructure.StructureMapControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) in C:\Apps\Development Source\CustomerResponsesApplication\trunk\CustomerResponses\Infrastructure\StructureMapControllerFactory.cs:line 19
>      at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

**Another link gives me 500.24 error:**

> HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error
>   An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Part on Web.Config

system.webServer - section

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

<handlers>
  <add name="UrlRoutingHandler"
     preCondition="integratedMode"
     verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd"
     type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler,  
         System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
         PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</handlers>

<!--<handlers>
  <remove name="MvcHttpHandler" />
  <add name="MvcHttpHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="*.mvc" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</handlers>-->
```

Global.asax

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.gif/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*datepick}",
    new { datepick = @"(.*/)?jquery.datepick.css(/.*)?" });
    // ignore datepick.css file
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}",
    new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*chevron}",
    new { chevron = @"(.*/)?Images/Chevron.gif(/.*)?" });
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*iconhome}",
    new { iconhome = @"(.*/)?Images/IconHome.gif(/.*)?" });

routes.MapRoute("test", "testroute",
    new { controller = "compresponses", action = "list" });

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new {
        controller = "compresponses",
        action = "list",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    } // Parameter defaults               
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is:
your web.config file contains too much information.
IIS 7.5 when runs in intergated mode does not require any additional settings.
I would recomend to create blank mvc application and publish it onto webserver.
also i have seen
the error :

[HttpException]: The controller for path '/conrollername/pagename/1' was not found or does not implement IController. at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) at

where it says that the dll either system.web or system.web.mvc is not referenced from project.

My solution( might be not the best) but is: Right button on project where the error occured and copy the dlls local and this should help with the error.

as for error:
Another link gives me 500.24 error: HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

the best is to have iis console installed and open the project using iis console.

Answer (score 0):

Change your application pool properties to:

```
.NET Framework Version
-- .NET Framework *version*

Pipeline Mode
-- Classic
```